# Shopify Multipass with .net

Tags: .net, shopify

I am trying to implement Shopify Multipass in my "Development" store. I've enabled Multiplass and set "Accounts are required" in Checkout settings.

Created a new customer via API and getting this result when querying for this customer:

```
    {
  "accepts_marketing": false,
  "addresses": [],
  "created_at": "2019-02-14T14:17:17-05:00",
  "currency": "USD",
  "default_address": null,
  "email": "m1@yahoo.com",
  "first_name": "M1",
  "multipass_identifier": null,
  "last_name": "M1",
  "last_order_id": null,
  "last_order_name": null,
  "note": null,
  "orders_count": 0,
  "phone": null,
  "state": "disabled",
  "tags": "",
  "tax_exempt": false,
  "total_spent": 0,
  "updated_at": "2019-02-14T14:17:17-05:00",
  "verified_email": true,
  "metafields": null,
  "id": 892572631087
}
```

I run my process generating the token (using .net nuget)

https://github.com/uoc1691/ShopifyMultipassTokenGenerator/tree/master/ShopifyMultipassTokenGenerator

with this input:

```
  string json = "{\"created_at\":\"2019-02-14T14:17:17-05:00\",\"email\":\"m1@yahoo.com\"}";
        var url = pass.Process(json);

        return Redirect(url);
```

this is the generated output:

```
https://kitkatco.myshopify.com/account/login/multipass/A-8K9DQOTy_YFLqPv2UdB_iiubISltQy_bfASNtr8ylqsoz1uvx0JTPD06RdNUjX-26TCVp7NFjbjk1RNsYS20jH7YQNbzkikd6I613a3XLwU3XriMHRzEg8z4racDlzryst9PWmlS3_7pJbJN_dgVNHeadz3fz1z1L_e_JcyLo=
```

After the redirect I get "Invalid Multipass request"

- What am I doing wrong?
- Just to confirm, multipass_identifier is NULL when creating the user (should it be null?)
- What I am trying to achieve is to user/password protect shopify store so that only users that are logged in (through my external app) be allowed to enter the shopify store/view and purchase products. Is Multipass for this purpose?

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: May be you have already looked at this, but in the FAQs at [Multipass Docs] 
 (https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/plus/multipass) You need to set the multipass_identifier yourself if that customer already exists.

Comment: I don't get it. What should be passed into that field?

Comment: Disregard the above comment. I just checked and the sample code on Shopify website works fine. Are you sure you are passing the current time in created_at and not the customer_creation time ?

Comment: Yes! that was it. works. however when I query for this user "multipass_identifier" is null. Shouldn't it be populated after multipass was used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Multipass login is for store owners who have a separate website and a
>   Shopify store. It redirects users from the website to the Shopify
>   store and seamlessly logs them in with the same email address they
>   used to sign up for the original website.

So whenever you redirect a user with valid multipass URL, the user will be logged in and if the user does not exist than it is created first and then logged in.

> **multipass_identifier**
>
> At Shopify, we use email addresses as unique identifiers for customers
>   of a shop. If your site uses other identifiers (such as usernames), or
>   if it is possible that two different users of your site registered
>   with the same email address, you must set the unique identifier in the
>   "identifier" field to avoid security problems. If the email address is
>   always unique, you don't need to set the "identifier" field.

So on normal account creation, multipass_idenifier will be null and will only be populated if a user is created via multipass request and **identifier** field was specified.

```
created_at param is current timestamp (in ISO8601 encoding).
```

For the usecase you have mentioned above, I don't think it will work if you use the Shopify password protected store feature. I tested and it redirects you to password page and same token cannot be used again.